# Strange abbreviation זי"ע

Tags: grammar-dikduk

Apparently this abbreviation is supposed to mean זכותו יגן עלינו. Surely this is grammatically incorrect, as the word זכות is feminine, and the phrase should be זכותו תגן עלינו?

Comment: I've heard that in medieval Hebrew words ending with the oot sound ות were mostly considered masculine. I don't have the source but if you look through Zemirot Shabbat you'll find this to be quite true.

Comment: I dont think its a real noun at all. Just made up from the verb zocho.

Comment: http://books.google.com.au/books?id=ivTOgtCxTw4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=13220&st=&pgnum=194

Comment: http://www.ivelt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=5427&start=150 (the second post)

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that chassidim - who are the ones who generally use this expression - are largely not knowledgable in or interested in Hebrew grammar?

Comment: This sort of speculation is interesting, but in its current form it's another question, not an answer. Although this question has been closed as a duplicate, it couldn't hurt to edit your answer to be more, um, answer-y.